# python single line for loops

Tags: python

i'm using processing.py

i was following this tut (Java)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7frvcAHXps

and i'm wondering if i can use the same kind of for loop in python

```
for(int y = 0; y < height; y = y + cellSize):

    for(int x = 0; x < width; x = x + cellSize):

        rect(x, 0, cellSize, cellSize)
```

I receive an error when i try to run the code:

```
processing.app.SketchException: Maybe there's an unclosed paren or quote mark somewhere before this line?
```

I guess there's probably an easy but slightly different way to do the use the same kind of nested for loops (on a single line) in python

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about graphic design.

Comment: i'll remove it, i've posted in the wrong place :v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def drange(start, stop, step):
    """floating range
    code by gimel see:
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/
    """
    r = start
    while r < stop:
        yield r
        r += step

for y in drange(0, height, cellSize):
    for x in drange(0, width, cellSize):
        rect(x, 0, cellSize, cellSize)
```